# How to keep the specfic format of your text the same when deleting a record from a file

Tags: python, file, text

I have created a student database which has to have the students name and id , courses etc.
in the order **( id:name:courses:semester:year**)
joined by (:) like this

```
**Orginal text file**
1111:rikki:2:3:1
2222:jackk:2:3:1
3333:sam:3:3:1
```

however when I delete a record from the text file my format goes all bad and is on the same line
like  this , I wanted it to be like the same format
and it only deletes the id ( id : name : courses : semester : year)
**After running code**:
**rikki:2:3:1:2222:jackk:2:3:1:3333:sam:3:3:1:**

How can I make it delete the whole line with the student id as well as keep the format after deleteing

```
def remove_student():
infile = open("lol.txt", "r")
f = infile.readlines()
new_list = []
id = input('enter your id:')
for line in f:
    for item in line.split(':'):
        new_list.append(item.strip())
write_file = open("lol.txt",'w')
for lines in new_list:
    if lines != id:
        write_file.write(lines+':')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create your new list without the offending line, then write them in bulk.  Also note that you must be sure to close the file before you try to rewrite it.

```
def remove_student():
    with open("lol.txt", "r") as infile:
        f = infile.readlines()
    id = input('enter your id:')
    new_list = []
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(':')
        if items[0] != id:
            new_list.append(line)
    with open("lol.txt",'w') as write_file:
        write_file.writelines( new_list )

remove_student()
```

A better plan in a case like this is to have a single `ClassList` class, where you read all the lines in at the beginning.  Then you can make your changes to the list in memory, and periodically write the whole list back out.  You don't need to read/modify/write for every operation.